# How do I to run several commands at once at the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

When using Unix I can run several commands at the command line prompt in a row:

```
# command1; command2; command3
```

Or even chain them by checking the exit statuses:

```
# command1 && command2 && command3
```

Is same possible on Windows XP command prompt?

I often have to run several software building commands on Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a few options at the command prompt.

As @barlop mentioned, there's using `&&` to chain commands as long as the previous was successful.

There's also `||`, which will stop executing after the first successful command.

Finally, commands can be grouped with parenthesis `()`, as follows:

```
C:\>(
echo command 1
echo command 2
)
```

Grouping can also be used with other commands, such as `if` or `for`, allowing for things like:

```
C:\>for %i in (*.7z) do @(
md "%~ni"
cd "%~ni"
7za.exe x "%~fi"
cd ..
del "%i"
)
```

Comment: What you said about || being regardless of exit status, is wrong.  That also depends on exit status  see ntcmds.chm, it says "...Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command did not complete successfully ...." and try echo a || echo a   it just displays a once.

Comment: So Windows seems finally up to Unix here? :-)

Comment: worth noting, & is regardless of whether the previous was successful.

Answer (score 2):

In *cmd.exe* you can use **`&`** for chaining commands (like `;` in *sh*).

```
echo a & echo b
```

The `&&` and `||` operators work too.

Answer (score 1):

ntcmds.chm mentions
 under concepts.."cmd shell overview"

&&   Use to run the command following && only if the command preceding the symbol is successful

So you can do

```
C:\>echo a && echo a
```

added

& is more appropriate as an answer than &&

here from ntcmds.chm

& "Use to separate multiple commands on one command line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command."

&& "Use to run the command following && only if the command preceding the symbol is successful. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command completed successfully. "
(it's a boolean short circuit AND)

|| "Use to run the command following || only if the command preceding || fails. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command did not complete successfully (receives an error code greater than zero)."
(it's a boolean short circuit OR i.e. given the expression "A or B" where A and B are boolean values of TRUE or FALSE, it only needs one to be true, so if A is true it won't go as far as B because it won't need to, in order to make its evaluation)

Comment: Doh! Years of using the command-prompt and I’ve never noticed that `cmd` supports short-circuit boolean command-chaining. Thanks for pointing out `ntcmds.chm`. (Aww, `edlin` is “not available on Windows XP 64-Bit Edition”. Poop.)

Comment: @Synetech: `edlin` is still a 16-bit MS-DOS program, which cannot work in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @grawity, I know, and I miss it (though to be honest, I have completely forgotten how to use it).

Comment: @Synetech: There's always Cygwin `ed`.

Comment: @grawity, well like I said, I don’t even remember how to use Edlin (and besides, I have a DOS boot-disk and DOSBox if I want to). I prefer Notepad2 these days. Though, if 32-bit apps can be emulated and run on 64-bit, and the NTVDM is a 32-bit app that emulates 16-bit, then I can’t help but wonder if the NTVDM can be installed/made to run on 64-bit Windows, thus allowing 16-bit apps on 64-bit. I would assume not, otherwise they would have included it (though not necessarily; devs have been known to *force* upgrades/updates for business reasons, when not technically required).

Comment: @Synetech: AFAIK, NTVDM doesn't *emulate* 16-bit, it uses the CPU's native 16-bit mode. (Virtual 8086 or whatever it is.) When the CPU has been switched to 64-bit "long mode", it cannot switch back to 16-bit. This at least hasn't been Microsoft's decision... although, IMHO, it's good the OS doesn't have to care anymore about compatibility with 30-year-old junk.

Comment: Hey! Who you callin’ junk? I still have and love my very first computer; a 4/8MHz 16-bit system. `:-P`